# Python Dataframe column is list of dicts and how parse it

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have dataframe:

| id | name | describe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some | [{'id':20, 'name':'thisIwantAsNameColumn','value':'thisIwantasValueinRow'},{'id':22, 'name':'thisIwantAsNameColumn2','value':'thisIwantasValueinRow2'}] |
| 2 | some2 | [{'id':23, 'name':'thisIwantAsNameColumn','value':'thisIwantasValueinRow'},{'id':24, 'name':'thisIwantAsNameColumn2','value':'thisIwantasValueinRow2'}] |

and i want:

| id | name | thisIwantAsNameColumn | thisIwantAsNameColumn2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some | thisIwantasValueinRow | thisIwantasValueinRow2 |
| 2 | some2 | thisIwantasValueinRow | thisIwantasValueinRow2 |

i try write function, but it creates a new dataframe for me and I would then have to connect it through something and that doesn't work well:

```
def proccess_customFields(row):
    customF={}
    for item in row:                
        customF["custom_field-{}".format(item.get('name'))] = item.get('value')
        result= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(customF,orient='index').T
    return result
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a list of dict or a string looks like a list of dict?

Comment: @Corralien His example code shows that it is a list of dicts

Comment: @TomMcLean. I don't think so. It seems to be a json string...

Comment: @Corralien Can you be more specific? I don't understand what you mean now? It's data from the api, and this attribute has a list of dictionaries in it.

Comment: @Cesc. What I mean is Python doesn't output string with double quotes by default. So I think it's a JSON string and not a list of dict. Can you check my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of dict (and not a JSON string), you can try:

```
df1 = df.pop('describe').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({l.get('name'): l.get('value') for l in x}))
out = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
   id   name  thisIwantAsNameColumn  thisIwantAsNameColumn2
0   1   some  thisIwantasValueinRow  thisIwantasValueinRow2
1   2  some2  thisIwantasValueinRow  thisIwantasValueinRow2
```

Comment: @Corallien You're right, I probably misled with the name - the data type of the column (dtype) is object, but probably string. The solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Either if you have string or list the dtype will be object. What is the output of `print(type(df['describe'].iloc[0]))` please?

Comment: @ ok ...<class 'list'>

Comment: I'm surprised. What is the error message?

Comment: I wrote it wrong - I wrote quotation marks instead of an apostrophe. It shows me an error : KeyError: 'value' - in row with lambda func

Comment: I dont know why....but if i change `l['name']` and `l['value']` to  `l.get('name')` and `l.get('value')` , then works... Thank you

Comment: @Cesc. Nice point. I updated my answer according your comment. You have missing data in your list of dict.